# Marshalling HTML form input to JSON and writing to file, golang

Tags: html, json, forms, go

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12513963/how-to-read-input-from-a-html-form-and-save-it-in-a-file-golang/39215607#39215607) appeared as if it might answer my question, however I am not able to make the output write/save properly to "somefile.json" ( named "deck.json" in my code) no matter what I have tried. My guess is that the form input and the writer are missing each other due to the file being opened/closed at the wrong times, but I honestly do not know. I am attempting to shoehorn this example into a form that allows for a user to input terms and definitions that will save to a JSON file which will be referenced by a JavaScript-powered "flash card" app housed on another page.

Here is the code I have at this moment:

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Flashcards for Learning JS</title>
</head>
<body>
   <br>
<form action="/addcard" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="term" placeholder="Term">
   <br>
   <br>
   <input type="text" name="definition" placeholder="Definition">
   <br>
   <br>
   <input type="submit" value="Add Card">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

GO:

```
 package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "html/template"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

type Card struct {
    Term       string `json:"term"`
    Definition string `json:"definition"`
}

func open(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    t, _ := template.ParseFiles("Form.html")
    t.Execute(w, nil)
}

func addcard(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    f, err := os.Open("deck.json")
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), 500)
        return
    }

    card := new(Card)
    card.Term = r.FormValue("term")
    card.Definition = r.FormValue("definition")

    b, err := json.Marshal(card)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), 500)
        return
    }

    f.Write(b)
    f.Close()
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", open)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
    http.HandleFunc("/addcard", addcard)
}
```

Comment: Your not checking the error from `f.Write`, always check errors. Your file is read only.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't appear to be the case unless something is escaping me re: file permissions. The permissions for "deck.json" are currently set to allow for all users to read/write/execute.

Comment: No, it is the case, check the error from `Write`. You're opening the file with O_RDONLY: https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Open

Comment: Sorry, I'm still misunderstanding, and I'm at a loss as to how to error check Write after searching, but after reading the documentation more thoroughly, I see now that os.Open DOES default to O_RDONLY, but I'm also wondering how or why that would matter if the permissions for the file itself are set to 0666? Is it the way that Go is opening the file that does this only at the moment the code is executed? At any rate, I've amended the line to specify the following:
f, err := os.OpenFile("deck.json", os.O_APPEND, 0666)

Comment: @JimB implemented the error check from go by example for f.Write and didn't turn anything up: https://gobyexample.com/writing-files
Also tried re-specifying 
`f, err := os.OpenFile("deck.json", os.O_RDWR, 0666)` to no avail. What am I not getting?

Comment: You are also putting the `/` handler first, so you can't access the `/addcard` handler at all. That last comment will also fail to create a file without `O_CREATE`. The file permissions have nothing to do with the flags you use to open the file -- this isn't specific to Go, it's how POSIX OS's work. Check your errors, and add some logging to your code, and you'll see what's going on

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. Much appreciated from someone brand new to systems programming!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed per recommendations made by @JimB. Fixed handler order, and program successfully concatenates each successive submission as valid JSON to the file in question.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Flashcards for Learning JS</title>
</head>
<body>
   <br>
<form action="/addcard" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="term" placeholder="Term">
   <br>
   <br>
   <input type="text" name="definition" placeholder="Definition">
   <br>
   <br>
   <input type="submit" value="Add Card">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

GO:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "html/template"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

type Card struct { //defining the data structure for our virtual flashcards
    Term       string `json:"Term"`
    Definition string `json:"Definition"`
}

func open(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    t, _ := template.ParseFiles("addcard.html")
    t.Execute(w, nil)
}

func addcard(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    f, err := os.OpenFile("deck.json", os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), 500)
        return
    }
    defer f.Close()

    card := new(Card)
    card.Term = r.FormValue("term")
    card.Definition = r.FormValue("definition")

    b, err := json.Marshal(card)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), 500)
        return
    }

    f.Write(b)
    f.Close()
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/addcard", addcard)
    http.HandleFunc("/", open)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)

}
```